# ASP.NET MVC RenderAction in Angular 6 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, renderaction

I am trying to render PartialViewResult inside Angular 6 template (.html) which is necessary to use licenses in our current system. As that of course cannot be done I was wondering if there is any other way?

There were solutions like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'root-app-component',
  templateUrl: '/[controllerName]/[actionName]'
})
```

but that doesn't work for me as the console throws:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './/Angular/List' in '....\src\app'
```

Even if I try to fix the path to controller it doesn't work. 
Mind that I have `<base href="/">` included.